# Using conditional statements to validate text fields in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to hide the submit button on a form until the required fields have been completed using a checkForm button and if statements. I'm having problems getting it to work and I've been researching for possible answers but I'm stuck. I wondered if somebody to have a look at my code below and point me in the right direction.

```
submit_btn.visible=false;
checkForm_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, entryTest)
function entryTest():void{
arguments;
if (name_txt.text != "")
trace("name needs completing");
else if (email_txt.text != "")
trace("email needs completing");
else if (question_txt.text != "")
trace("question needs completing");
else submit_btn.visible=true;
}
```

Here is a copy of the code that I have edited following some suggestions - but it still isn't working correctly. I am only receiving an output for the first if statement.

```
submit_btn.visible=false;
checkForm_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, entryTest)
function entryTest(event:MouseEvent):void{
  if(name_txt.text != ""){
    trace("name needs completing");
  } else if(email_txt.text != ""){
    trace("email needs completing");
  } else if(question_txt.text != ""){
    trace("question needs completing");
  } else {
    submit_btn.visible = true
  }
}
```

Comment: what is `arguments;` on line 4 suppose to be?

Comment: I put arguments in try to resolve errors I was receiving but now I have added the braces so that line is not needed.

Comment: the tests need to be reversed to `==` instead of `!=`

Answer (score 1):

you have a syntax error.

```
else (submit_btn.visible=true);
```

should be

```
else
  submit_btn.visible = true;
```

To be complete though, your button event handler should be declaring the datatype expected for the event that is passed... and you'll likely find that using braces `{}` to wrap your blocks of code should help clarify what is the condition and what is the code that executes when that condition is met. (it also makes it easy to add/remove more code without having to know if you need to add the brackets or not)

```
function entryTest(event:MouseEvent):void{
  if(name_txt.text == ""){
    trace("name needs completing");
  } else if(email_txt.text == ""){
    trace("email needs completing");
  } else if(question_txt.text == ""){
    trace("question needs completing");
  } else {
    submit_btn.visible = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: As suggested in your message above I've used braces around the blocks of code but I am still only receiving validation for the first if statement. I've also changed the operators to !=. Any other ideas?

Comment: submit_btn.visible=false;
checkForm_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, entryTest)
function entryTest(event:MouseEvent):void{
  if(name_txt.text != ""){
    trace("name needs completing");
  } else if(email_txt.text != ""){
    trace("email needs completing");
  } else if(question_txt.text != ""){
    trace("question needs completing");
  } else {
    submit_btn.visible = true
  }
}

Comment: I copied your code edits but I think they should be reversed.  You want to compare against an empty string and only continue if filled in. (currently you are hitting the first condition and thus not showing the button)